# Converting char to wide char

Tags: c++, windows, char, wchar

I am trying to converts a sequence of multibyte characters to a corresponding sequence of wide characters using the `mbstowcs_s` function. But I keep having the following heap corruption problem. Can anyone tell me how to fix that?

[image]

Here is a sample code. When debugging, it is always the line `delete wc_name` causing the problem. I know it shouldn't be it.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) { 
    size_t returnValue; // The number of characters converted.
    const size_t sizeInWords = 50; // The size of the wcstr buffer in words
    const char* c_name = "nanana"; // The address of a sequence of characters
    wchar_t *wc_name = new wchar_t(50); 

    errno_t err = mbstowcs_s(&returnValue, wc_name, sizeInWords, 
                                              c_name, strlen(c_name) );

    wcout << wc_name << endl;
    delete wc_name;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`wchar_t *wc_name = new wchar_t(50);` should be `wchar_t *wc_name = new wchar_t[50];` to allocate an array. And corresponding `delete wc_name` should be `delete[] wc_name;`. BTW, if you know the size of the array at compile time itself, there is no need for dynamic memory allocation. You can simply do `wchar_t wc_name[50];`.